# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 deployed code not working in IE8 in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app. It is working fine in both IE8 & FF when we run VS2010. I have deployed this code in IIS 7.5. Now, the deployed app is working fine in FF, but not in IE8. I am getting error:

**Stop running this script?
A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly...**

See following screen-shot:

[image]

I tested the published code in IIS6, It's working fine in both FF and IE8.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using some javascript which is entering a loop of some sort (possibly recursion)

Either comment out one function at a time to see which function is the culprit, or do it in binary-search fashion and comment out half at a time to narrow it down.

Finally, is there something out of the ordinary about your page? If the your javascript (or one of your libraries) was not the culprit, start ripping out chunks of your code to narrow the problem down.

Unfortunately there is not a quick answer to this one...

Comment: Then Why it's not coming when we run from VS2010 for same database

Comment: The same javascript isn't necessarily going to be a problem with each browser. Each browser interprets javascript a little bit differently. Some are more tolerant to long-running scripts than others. I am confident that if you follow my methodology that you will identify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to try to determine what's going on with your JavaScript. Try reloading the browser. You can also try downloading the Ajax profiling bits at
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AjaxView
This can help determine your slow functions. You could also load up the JavaScript debugger and break into the code as well
What nonstandard javascript libraries are you running? Any?

Since your app runs differently seemingly only based on iis version differences compare a session on one to a session on the other using 'Fiddler'